# Laravel 5 Add another parameter to check on login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I used the `make:auth` to scaffold the registration/login system. I was wondering how do I add another parameter to check on the login, besides checking if the username and password correspond to the matching DB row?

EDIT: I tried looking online and I found I could change it in the Auth::Attempt line but those are all for Laravel 5.2 and below. The LoginController has this:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

From what I understand, that redirects to the middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated`, but then that middleware is like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I'm almost sure I have to add a custom guard, but even at the docs I looked online, it was kinda confusing.. Anybody have a link that explains this really well? Or maybe a sample code?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I edited the post

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do it by overriding a `AuthenticatesUsers`'s [credentials()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L77) method in your **LoginController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials['active'] = 1;

    return $returnArray;
}
```

This example is of most common use case where user can login only if his account is active.

---

If you want to use other table instead of `users`, you need to [customize guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authentication-quickstart)

Add one in **config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        ...
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
],

...

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        ...
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Customer::class,
    ],
],
```

And then, add this in your **LoginController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('customer');
}
```

As specified in docs, you can use the same in `RegisterController` and `ResetPasswordController` as well.

Comment: But where can I change the query to select from another table instead of `users`?